# About the convergence of $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^{F_{k}}}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, fibonacci-numbers

Consider the following summation:

> $$S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^{F_{k}}}$$

Where $F_n$ is the nth [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Some of the values are listed below:

> $$
> \begin{array}{r|rr}
> n&S_n&\\\hline1&1\\
> 5&\;\;\;1.627056\overline{1}&\\
> 8&≈1.62705670649561296431951406885467949\\
> 15&≈1.62705670649561296431951406885468308&\\
> 20&≈1.62705670649561296431951406885468308&\\
> 50&≈1.62705670649561296431951406885468308
> \\
> 100&≈1.62705670649561296431951406885468308\\
> 200&≈1.62705670649561296431951406885468308\\
> \end{array}
> $$

As it's clear the convergence of this sum is so fast.

---

Using the fact $k\le F_{k}$ for $6\le k$ we conclude that:

$$1<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{F_{k}}}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{k}}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}=e-1≈1.71828182846$$

The question is that how it can be shown that what does the series converge to by calculation.

Comment: $F_k$ has exponential growth, so the series converges very fast.

Comment: If you are trying to find an explicit expression for the limit of the series, then I have no idea how can it be done.

Comment: Don't see any reason for a closed form to be doable.